# UICollectionView multiple selection doesn't deselect first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've this issue with multiple selection in `UICollectionView`.

When I want select multiple cell simultaneously I use `self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;`

Suppose I tap on item at rows 0,1,2,3 (in this order), so when I remove the multiple selection setting `self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;` the item at row = 0 remains selected.

What I forgot? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually interesting. But nope, it is not a bug!

Fist of all, here are two different settings for `UICollectionView` that you need to pay attention to for your question:

**allowsMultipleSelection**

> A Boolean value that determines whether users can select more than one item in the collection view.

**allowsSelection**

> If the value of this property is YES (the default), users can select items.

By default, `allowsMultipleSelection` is set to `NO` and `allowsSelection` is set to `YES`. So you will be able to select cell but no more than one.

When you set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES` and select multiple cells and suddenly change the value back to `NO`, only one of the cells will remain selected. However, it doesn't necessary be the first one. In your case, any of the cells 0, 1, 2, 3 could be selected while the others are deselected. Apple doesn't seems to have a documentation of this behaviour. If you want to disable selection, setting `allowsSelection` to `NO` is a right way to do.